# change react native base floating label, label color

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

Im using react native with native base framework. I have added a floatingLabel to my screen and i need to change the color of its label.

I tried color:'#ffffff' in label, it works fine untill i click on it. I use xcode ios simulator, when i click the floating label after changing the label color it gives me the following error,

TypeError: In this environment the sources for assign MUST be an object. This error is a performance optimization and not spec compliant.

Any idea why this happen and how to change floating input label color?

Comment: It would be easy to help if you can provide code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats quite simple and straight forward

```
<Form>
    <Item floatingLabel>
    <Label style={{ color: "red" }}>Username</Label>
        <Input />
    </Item>
</Form>
```

[image: Output example]

Comment: Hi, I have to change only moving up placeholder text color. is it possible ? if yes then how ?

Comment: Not possible with theme
You may have to check conditions, if `floatUp` is called then change `Label` color

Comment: This is a very common behavior of the material when the input is focused, the floating label font size reduces, color changes to the primary color. This is the worst implementation.